# LaTeX code from Geogebra does not compile

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to export a graph from Geogebra, and compilation returns the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
./ggb.tex:29: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   n
l.29 \end{axis}
```

As soon as I comment the 2 lines starting with \draw , compilation works.

Can you help me out understand how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{zzttff}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,1}
\definecolor{ffvvqq}{rgb}{1,0.3333333333333333,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-10.400000000000004,
xmax=11.24,
ymin=-8.730000000000004,
ymax=6.370000000000003,
xtick={-10,-9,...,11},
ytick={-8,-7,...,6},]
\clip(-10.4,-8.73) rectangle (11.24,6.37);
%\draw[line width=2pt,color=ffvvqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-10.400000000000004:11.24] plot(\x,{2*((\x)-1)^(1/(3))+1});
%\draw[line width=2pt,color=zzttff,smooth,samples=100,domain=-10.400000000000004:11.24] plot(\x,{((\x))^(1/(3))});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=ffvvqq] (-10.16,-3.24) node {$g$};
\draw[color=zzttff] (-10.16,-1.94) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On quick glance, without any test, replacing package pgfplot by tikz is worth a try.

Comment: I believe the issue is that, for some values of `\x`, you are essentially taking the cubic root of a negative number (which is complex), and pgf does not know how to plot that. Evidence: If you replace `((\x)-1)` with `abs((\x)-1)` it seems to work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround, if you don't want to dive into the coding:

[image: cubic roots]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{zzttff}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,1}
\definecolor{ffvvqq}{rgb}{1,0.3333333333333333,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-10.5,
xmax=11.5,
ymin=-8.5,
ymax=6.5,
xtick={-10,-9,...,11},
ytick={-8,-7,...,6},]
\clip(-10,-8) rectangle (11,6);

\draw[line width=2pt,color=ffvvqq,smooth,samples=500,domain=-10:1] plot(\x,{-2*(abs((\x)-1))^(1/(3))+1}) coordinate (a);
\draw[line width=2pt,color=ffvvqq,smooth,samples=500,domain=11:1] plot(\x,{2*(abs((\x)-1))^(1/(3))+1}) coordinate(b);
\draw[line width=2pt,color=ffvvqq](a)--(b);

\draw[line width=2pt,color=zzttff,smooth,samples=500,domain=-10:0] plot(\x,{-(abs(\x))^(1/(3))}) coordinate (a);
\draw[line width=2pt,color=zzttff,smooth,samples=500,domain=11:0] plot(\x,{(abs(\x))^(1/(3))})  coordinate(b);
\draw[line width=2pt,color=zzttff](a)--(b);

\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=ffvvqq] (-10.16,-3.24) node {$g$};
\draw[color=zzttff] (-10.16,-1.94) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With all your guidance + the easy code to fix my issue, I want to thank you!!!! :-)

Comment: Nice. Feel free to accept the answer, then.